# Finding long paths

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a sparse unweighted directed graph of 1000000 nodes and I would like to find all simple paths of length 5.  I know there will be very few simple paths of length 5 (maybe only one).

I see from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem that the parameterized complexity of determining if a graph has a path of length k is O(2^k n poly(n,k))) although I don't know if these methods will also solve my problem.  Unfortunately all the methods I have found look very complicated and it seems unimplemented.

Can someone explain in more or less simple words a fast solution which I can then implement?

Comment: How sparse will the graph be? Is it generated randomly, following some distributions or is a real dataset? Can it be divided into connected components, or will there be bridges that separate the graph into relatively big sub ones?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei There are a few edges per vertex on average (fewer than 10). The whole graph is *weakly* connected. It is a real dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an [implementation of the Color-Coding method](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/colorcoding/) for Longest Path. However, it was only tested with graphs of about 10000 vertices; also, it might not find all size-5 paths (it was designed to find a small set of interesting paths). I might be able to adapt it to your purposes, drop me a line if you're interested.

**Edit:** The idea of Color-Coding is to randomly color the vertices of the graphs with 5 colors. The hope is that the 5 vertices of the path we're looking for all receive different colors. If this is true, we can find it with dynamic programming. Of course, the probability is only 0.0384; but if we repeat the whole procedure e.g. 500 times, there's only a chance of about 3*10^-9 that we miss it. That's just the basic scheme, there are many tricks to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks very much! How long did it take for your data?

Comment: For a graph with 7000 vertices and 20000 edges and pathlength 5, about one second.

Comment: I will definitely try it out and read your paper and get back to you. Thanks again.